# How do I insert a tuple into an existing dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't think this is a duplicate question, as I need to add to an existing dictionary, not create a new one.

```
results = dict()

if xxx:
    (rslt_string, rslt_msg) = func1
    (rslt_string, rslt_msg) = func2
    (rslt_string, rslt_msg) = func5
if yyy:
    (rslt_string, rslt_msg) = func3
    (rslt_string, rslt_msg) = func5
if zzz:
    (rslt_string, rslt_msg) = func2
    (rslt_string, rslt_msg) = func5

# How do I add each tuple to the results dict with rslt_string being the key and rslt_msg being the value so that I can do this below?
# Overwriting is ok (good even) if identical key

for (name, msg) in results:
    if msg is not "":
        test_failed(name)
```

Is there a better Python pattern for aggregating the results of some test functions whose call status is dynamic?  In my case I have a number of tests to run on the results of a parser. Depending on the type of expression some tests (methods) should be run but not others. I don't know which ones will be needed until run time, but I want to log which ones, if any, fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll work:

```
results = dict()

if xxx:
    results.update((func1(), func2(), func5()))
if yyy:
    results.update((func3(), func5()))
if zzz:
    results.update((func2(), func5()))
```

You may update the `results` dict with the first value of the tuple being the key and the second being the value.

Comment: Ahh, I was trying to use update on the tuple directly (or a list). Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BrianHVB if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: As far as I understand, `dict` is slightly redundant, `results.update((func1(), func2(), func5()))` works, too.

Comment: Hmm, breaks when there is only a single function. Weird behavior but I think it has to do with Python not recognizing a single element set?

Comment: @BrianHVB a single element  tuple should be declared like this `(func1(),)`.

Comment: @BrianHVB In a single element you can just do `rslt_string, rslt_msg = func1()` and `results[rslt_string] = rslt_msg`.